# Изменение значения ProgressBar на C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker, делегаты

У меня есть приложение на wpf, которое достаточно долго пингует ряд ip-шников.
Захотелось установить ProgressBar.
Напрямую (Как в Windows Forms - изменяя счетчик) - не работает.

Нагуглила, что это частая проблема.
Нашла два решения:

1. Наиболее частое и популярное с BackgroundWorker ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774473/using-backgroundworker-with-progressbar-in-wpf)). Решение не поняла и применить не смогла, т.к. не смогла засунуть свою функциональность в DoWork.
2. Решение с делегатами ([Habr](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/38787/), [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38555/WebControls/)). Такой метод у меня полностью заработал и все хорошо.

Очень хочу понять смысл того, что мы делаем в примененном мною способе. Читаю про делегаты, но не могу понять, зачем мы тут их используем.

Прошу пояснить механику работы второго варианта и причину его меньшей популярности (оптимизация?).

Спасибо!

P.S. Я абсолютный новичок в C#.

Comment: Тут дело даже не в c#, надо понимать что по-умолчанию существует только один процесс(поток) который "рисует" и "вычисляет" . Установка % в прогрес-баре не означает что он будет перерисован. Он перерисутется или по завершению вычислений (но тогда прогрес бар не отображается до конца вычислений), или принудительной перерисовкой. Как вариант 2 - вычисления делает второй поток(thread), а перерисовку первый. В с++ и Delphi точно-такая же проблема.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, без него не вполне понятно, где ваша проблема.

Comment: Если проблема в том, что вы всё делаете в главном потоке, то правильное решение — с async/await.

Comment: Попробуйте после назначения процента  сделать progressbar.refresh (или repaint) а за тем `Application.DoEvents()` что б он принудительно отрисовался.

Comment: @nick_n_a: DoEvents в WPF вроде же нет? (и слава богу)

Comment: VladD, у меня нет проблемы, код к меня работает. Мне интересно, как работает то решение, которое я взяла из CodeProject (ссылка выше). Так как самой у меня разобраться не получилось.

nick_n_a, спасибо! Теперь мне понятна основная проблема. Я ее представляла несколько иначе. А что делает перерисовку в варианте с делегатами?...

Comment: В  CodeProject очень хорошо прокомментированый код. Делегат служит этакой "палочкой выручалочкой" за которую "тянут" и вызывают из `Dispatcher.Invoke()` метод ProgressBar1.SetValue();

Comment: [Вот этот же код](http://blog.dvteam.ru/?p=125) с комментами на русском

Comment: @777Julia777, _А что делает перерисовку в варианте с делегатами?_ Dispatcher. В WPF, как я понимаю вы не можете отрисовать что либо на UI, пока Ваше приложение условно не перейдет в состояние Idle. Для решение этой проблемы существует `Dispatcher` который позволяет выполнить какой-то код в UI потоке, не дожидаясь завершения длительной операции. P.S. но сегодня можно юзать `async/await`.

Comment: Bulson, Anton Komyshan, спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите.

Один из основных принципов в UI-программировании — это то, что вся работа с интерфейсом должна вестить в UI-потоке. Если вы используете привязку к свойствам какого-то объекта, то и эти свойства нужно обновлять в UI-потоке. Из этого всё и следует.

Если вы выполняете длительную операцию (например, тот же многократный пинг), то ваша операция сама по себе не может бежать в UI-потоке. Значит, её придётся перенести в фоновый поток, а запросы на обновление UI отправлять в UI-поток.

Как именно можно отправить запрос на обновление UI в UI-поток? Для этого есть несколько методов. Базовый метод — использовать `Dispatcher`, у которого есть функции `InvokeAsync`/`Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`, и передать ему *часть кода*. А что есть часть кода? Это по сути функция, которую вы создаёте либо непосредственно, либо через лямбду. Поскольку C# — типизированный язык, сигнатуру этой функции необходимо описать.

Вот делегат и есть описание этой самой сигнатуры. Переменная делегатного типа представляет собой функцию, которая отправляется диспечером в UI-поток, и там выполняется. Вот и всё!

---

Добавлю ещё, что в случае `BackgroundWorker`'а `DoWork` выполняется в фоновом потоке, а события `ProgressChanged` в UI-поток перенаправляет `BackgroundWorker` самостоятельно (и скорее всего при помощи такого же трюка с делегатами).

Answer (score 0):

Можно завести потоки или как вариант использовать invoke. К примеру, в коде формы будет что то в духе

```
public void ProgressBarHandler(int value){
... пингуем машины
 progressBar.Value +=value;
}
```

и вызываешь

```
MainForm.Dispather.Invoke(new ThreadStart(delegate(MainForm.ProgressBarHandler(1);}));
```

Comment: `MainForm.Dispather` - этот вариант не годен для WPF, здесь другое `Application.Current.Dispatcher`. Кроме того, вопрос был в духе: "зачем здесь делегат?".